# Extract only digits for each string from list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list, integer

Currently, I'm doing a bit of web scraping.  One of my extractions returns full IDs for each item on the site.

Looks like:

```
['ID: 1234', 'ID: 456', 'ID: 8899']
```

I would like to run an iterator that returns only integer values from each item in the list.

Like **(preferred)**:

```
[1234, 456, 8899]
```

I've seen many questions that pertain to extracting integers, yet they all suggested solutions return each numeric as an index in the new list, as such **(current)**:

```
[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,8,8,9,9]
```

I can get that going with a:

```
testList = []
for i in list:
     id = re.findall('\d+', i)
     testList.append(id)
```

But I'm looking for that extra step to get it in the preferred output.  Any list comprehension with regex combination advice?

Additionally, if this is a duplicate, a link will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l=['ID: 1234', 'ID: 456', 'ID: 8899']
print([int(x.split(':')[1]) for x in l])
```

Ouput

```
[1234, 456, 8899]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great. If I may ask, what is the functionality of the [1] index?

Comment: @AVI getting the second element of the result of `split`

Comment: @AVI    x.split(':') return a list like ['ID' ,'1234']. [1] selects the second element from it (index starts from 0)

Answer (score 0):

The easist way is to split every element in the list since it seperate 'ID:' and number with a space ' ':

```
lst = ['ID: 1234', 'ID: 456', 'ID: 8899']
testList = []

for ele in lst:
   id_num = ele.split()[1]
   testList.append(id_num)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works great.  If I may ask, what is the functionality of the [1] index on the ele.split?

Comment: @AVI getting the second element of the result of `split`

Comment: Because .split() will return ['ID:', '1234'], so the second element is what we want.

Answer (score 0):

`str.isnumeric` checks if a string can be interpreted as a number. If you are trying to get numbers no matter the position you should use this.

```
lst = ['ID: 1234', 'ID: 456', 'ID: 8899']
nums = list(map(lambda s:int(''.join([c for c in s if c.isnumeric()])), lst))
print(nums) # [1234, 456, 8899]
```

But if you know that the format will always have the `ID:` then bitto's answer would be best.

Answer (score 0):

```
test = []
id = ['ID: 1234', 'ID: 456', 'ID: 8899']
test.append([int(x.split(':')[1]) for x in id])

print(test)
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list comprehension with tuple unpacking:

```
>>> l = ['ID: 1234', 'ID: 456', 'ID: 8899']
>>> [int(y.lstrip()) for _, y in (z.split(':') for z in l)]
[1234, 456, 8899]
```

Which also uses [`str.lstrip()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/lstrip.html) to strip whitespace from the left of the string before converting to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to find all matching entries. The pattern below
captures all the matching digits in a list.
Then, map transforms each of the input string in the captured list to an integer.

```
>>> import re
>>> data = "['ID: 1234', 'ID: 456', 'ID: 8899']"
>>> map(lambda x: int(x), re.findall("'ID: (\d+)'", data))
[1234, 456, 8899]
>>>
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Updated. Thanks @RoyScheffers!